# How to update field within nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux, nested

I have an extremely nested state and I am trying to update a field within an object within the options array.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  player1: {
    name: null,
    options: [{
      A: null
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }, {
      A: null
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  player2: {
    name: null,
    options: [{
      A: null
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }, {
      A: null
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }]
  },
}
```

For example, given `name = "player1 2 B"` and `value = "cheese"`, I can update state.player1.options[2].b of my options array with:

```
const keys = name.split(" ");
const player = keys[0]
const idx = keys[1]
const field = keys[keys.length - 1]

return merge({}, state, {
  [player]: {
    ...[player],
    options: state[player].options.map((option, i) => 
      i === idx ? { ...option, [field]: value } : { ...option } 
    )
  }
```

1. How would I make this more dynamic to be able to update field state.player1.options[1].B.extra?
2. What if there was another nesting after extra?

Comment: If you pass in an object rather than an array, you might be able to simply merge it with the existing state.

Comment: I have to use an array for options because it contain multiple objects

Answer (score 1):

If you fancy using a library, this can be simplified by using [map-factory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-factory)

The code will look like this

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  player1: {
    name: null,
    options: [{
      A: null,
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }, {
      A: null,
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  player2: {
    name: null,
    options: [{
      A: null,
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }, {
      A: null,
      B: {
        isUse: null,
        amount: null,
        extra: {
          X: null,
          Y: null
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};

const mapper = require("map-factory")();

mapper
 .map()
 .set("player1.options[1].B", {"hi": "bye"});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapper.execute(INITIAL_STATE), null, 2));
```

You can go as many levels as you want using this way.